# Label objects from two images based on position

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I'm trying to label the objects according to their position in 2 or more images.
The basic algorithm should be simple in theory:

- select item from img_a
- check if it overlaps with any object in img_b

  - check if it overlaps with only one object in img_b

    - If yes both have the same label
  - else: check largest overlap and assign label accordingly

The image below helps to visualise the problem, where the image on the left would be the segmentation map from img_b, the right image would be the segmentation goal for img_a (countour from img_b in red is just for reference and should not belong to the result).

[Labelling goal example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8sfK.jpg)

Those images are not exactly the images I'm using, but they are very similar. The objects have irregular shapes (red object/group on the middle image as example) and large variation in size and irregularly distributed along the image. When I apply the solution shown below, I notice many missing objects in the target seg_map, as if no overlap was found, even when img_b is the union of img_a and another image.

Until now I've been trying by generating a dataframe with the bboxes and a segmentation map for the images (via cv.connectedComponentWithStats()). Then I try to match the objects by testing if any bounding box overlaps, if yes i set a new label as a column in the df. The next step is to just map the values from the seg_map based on the "new" label value.

for testing: [img_a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dsHM.jpg) [img_b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9z1I.jpg)

```py
def create_table_from_bin(bin_img):
    connectivity = 8

    nb_components, seg_map, stats, centroids =  cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(bin_img, connectivity,  cv.CV_32S)

    spots_df = pd.DataFrame(stats)
    spots_df.columns = ['x', 'y', 'w', 'h', 'Area']
    spots_df['centroids_x'] = centroids[:, 0]
    spots_df['centroids_y'] = centroids[:, 1]
    
    for i in range(nb_components):
        if spots_df['Area'].loc[i] < 50:
            seg_map[seg_map==i] = 0
            spots_df = spots_df.drop(i)

    spots_df = spots_df.drop(0)

    return spots_df, seg_map
```

```
def overlap(bbox1, bbox2):
    #for x axis 
    if (bbox1.x < bbox2.x < (bbox1.x + bbox1.w)) or (bbox1.x < (bbox2.x + bbox2.w)< (bbox1.x + bbox1.w)):
        if (bbox1.y < bbox2.y < (bbox1.y + bbox1.h)) or (bbox1.y < (bbox2.y + bbox2.h)< (bbox1.y + bbox1.h)):
            return True
    return False

def match_tables(df_a, df_b):
 
    
    match_table = df_b.copy()
    
    df0 = df_a.copy()
    df1 = df_b.copy()
    
    match_table['label'] = None
    
    
    for i in tqdm(df1.index):
        for o in df0.index:
            if match_table['label'].loc[o]==None:
                if overlap(df1.loc[i], df0.loc[o]):
                    match_table['label'].loc[o] = i



    return match_table
```

Comment: Something is not clear to me. Object are identified on image_a then used for image_b1, image_b2 etc? Or you add not overlapping objects in image_b1 to the object from image_a to search in image_b2, and so on? What does it means "label accordingly"? Can you post a sample of img_a specifying the objects and a sample of image_b then the expected result? The images currently posted are confusing to me.

Comment: My explanation wasn't very clear, sorry about that I edited the question and the images, maybe it helps. About the images, I still need 1 reputation point to embed them, please check the links and you will find the images. Another way to formulate: I have img_b labelled as ground truth, then I get img_a "put" it over img_b and all the objects from img_a that overlap with objects in img_b should receive the same label as img_b. It can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8sfK.jpg) with the colors as labels